# how release memory of a dynamic array in c++

Tags: c++

I have a dynamic array in c++ that defined like this:

```
string** CommunityNodes = new string *[10000];
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) {
     CommunityNodes[i] = new string[1000];
}
```

If the array type would be in int type, i can release it like this:

```
int ** array_iter = CommunityNodes;
    while(*array_iter){
            delete(*array_iter++);
}
delete CommunityNodes;
```

but my array type is string and by the above way, i get some errors. so how can I release the alocated memory of this dynamic array?

Comment: Use `std::vector<std::string>` or at least define your own class with explicit constructors and destructors.....

Comment: *"If the array type would be in int type, i can release it like this:"* -- No, you can't.

Comment: Save yourself some frustration, use `std::vector`.

Comment: You have just won the "2 stars programmer" badge. Congratulations.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch... which is exception safe and follows the rule of three.

Answer (score 5):

If you allocate memory using `new []`, you need to use `delete []`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) {
    delete [] CommunityNodes[i];
}
delete [] CommunityNodes;
```

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum I was going to say "Jinx", since I think we were about thirty seconds apart... :-)

Comment: no reason to have two identical answers - I'll delete if its even 5 secs unless I have something different to say